# Google Apps Script - How to Update Code to Have Tabs Containing the Same Word in Name Split Into the Same Google Sheets File?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm using the following code to turn tabs in a Google Sheets file into separate Google Sheets files. One challenge that I have is that there's some tabs that have similar names and I don't want to have separate Google Sheets files for them.

For ex: Say there's 5 tabs in the Google Sheets file: tab1: 'Toys Check', tab2: 'Toys Checked', tab3: 'Clothes Check', tab4: 'Video Games Check', tab5: 'Video Games Checked'. Right now, the below code will create 5 separate Google Sheet's files for them. However, I want the code to create 3 separate Google Sheets files instead. The first Google Sheets file would contain 2 tabs: tab1: 'Toys Check' and tab2: 'Toys Checked'. The second Google Sheets file would just have 'Clothes Check' tab. The third Google Sheets file would also contain 2 tabs: tab1: 'Video Games Check' and tab2: 'Video Games Checked'.

Below is a visual of the above example:
[image]

How can the below code be updated to ensure that tabs that have the same name (minus the 'check' or 'checked' part of the tab name) would end up being split into the same Google Sheets file? For the file name, is it possible to make it so that it is the same as the unique category + 'Summary'. So in the above example, the file name for the Google Sheets file that contains 'Toys Check' and 'Toys Checked' tabs would be 'Toys Summary'.

```
function copySheetsToFolder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var folderId = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next().getId();
  for (var n in ss.getSheets()) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[n];
    var name = sheet.getName();
    if (name != 'ControlTab' && name != 'RawData') {
      var alreadyExist = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
      while (alreadyExist.hasNext()) {
        alreadyExist.next().setTrashed(true);
      }
      var newSS = Drive.Files.insert({ title: name, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{ id: folderId }] }, null, { supportsAllDrives: true });
      var copy = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSS.id);
      sheet.copyTo(copy).setName(name);
      copy.deleteSheet(copy.getSheets()[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, I think that the rule of your sheet name is required to be known. From your question, all sheet names are `string + number`? And, do you want to search only the string from the sheet name like `string + number`? Or, you are using the sheet names of other rules? And about `However, I want the code to create 2 separate Google Sheets files instead.`, in this case, what is the Spreadsheet name? For example, what is the Spreadsheet name for the Spreadsheet including `tab1: 'Toys 2002' and tab2: 'Toys 2005'`?

Comment: And, in your showing script, the file of `var alreadyExist = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name)` is removed every loop. In your goal, do you want to remove all Spreadsheets and create a new Spreadsheet? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike, your questions made me revisit the goal and I realized that my question is wrong. I will resubmit a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you updated your question, I would like to check it.

Comment: @Tanaike, I've updated the question. I kept it mostly the same but I changed the example a bit. I've also answered your question related to the how to handle the file name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, in order to populate the similarly named tabs, do you want to check the value by removing the values of `check` or `checked`? Are there other rules of the sheet name? And, the sheet name of `Toys Check` is always `Toys Check`? Isn't this `ToysCheck`? And, in your showing script, the file of `var alreadyExist = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name)` is removed every loop. In your goal, do you want to remove all Spreadsheets and create a new Spreadsheet?

Comment: There are no other rules for the sheet name. It's currently Toys but I would prefer it to be Toys Check versus ToysCheck for visual purposes. The real data has a lot of category names in the raw dataset so it won't just be Toys and Video Games. Yes, if there is a file in the folder with the same file name, I want it to be overwritten

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike . I edited my question with an image to better show what I'm trying to do. Does it make more sense now or should I submit a new question and see if I can do a better job?

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. From your added images, in your situation, the suffix of the sheet name is always `Checked` or `Check`. Is my understanding correct? Because, in your situation, I thought that it is required to know the format of your sheet name. By correctly understanding your situation, I would like to think of a solution. I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Thank you for responding back. Yes, the suffix of of the sheet name will always be either Checked or Check

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. I tried out the code and found one issue. I commented about it under the solution you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve a goal shown in your question using Google Apps Script.
- The suffix of the sheet names are always `Check` or `Checked`.
- You want to give the new Spreadsheet names like `### Summary`.
- From your showing script, you want to remove the existing Spreadsheets in the parent folder of the active Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const exclude = ['ControlTab', 'RawData']; // This is from your showing script.
  const suffix = ["Checked", "Check"]; // This is from your comment.
  const newSuffix = "Summary"; // This is from your question.

  // Retrieve active Spreadsheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Create an object for creating new Spreadsheets by splitting sheets.
  const obj = ss.getSheets().reduce((o, s) => {
    const name = s.getSheetName();
    if (!exclude.includes(name)) {
      const n = name.replace(new RegExp(suffix.join("|")), "").trim();
      o[n] = o[n] ? [...o[n], s] : [s];
    }
    return o;
  }, {});

  // Retrieve files from the parent folder and create a file object.
  const folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  const fileObj = {};
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const f = files.next();
    fileObj[f.getName()] = f;
  }

  // Create new Spreadsheets including several sheets.
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([ssName, sheets]) => {
    const newSSName = `${ssName} ${newSuffix}`;
    if (fileObj[newSSName]) {
      fileObj[newSSName].setTrashed(true);
    }
    const newss = SpreadsheetApp.create(newSSName);
    sheets.forEach(s => s.copyTo(newss).setName(s.getName()));
    newss.deleteSheet(newss.getSheets()[0]);
    DriveApp.getFileById(newss.getId()).moveTo(folder);
  });
}
```

- The variables `exclude`, `suffix` and `newSuffix` are from your question and your comment.
- When this script is run, several new Spreadsheets including several sheets are created in the same folder of the active Spreadsheet. Each sheet in a Spreadsheet is retrieved from the sheet name.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I appreciate you trying to help me! The code almost worked as intended. There is just one issue. The google sheets files that are created using this code don't contain the data that was in each sheet. Do you why the data in each cell didn't get copied over within a sheet?

Comment: @scriptnewb Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your reply, I noticed that I misunderstood your goal. I had thought that you wanted to create new sheets by the sheet names. So, from your reply, the sheets are copied to the created new Spreadsheet. Please confirm it again.